# Connection timeout between windows servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, iis-6, citrix

Assume I have two Windows servers (2012 R2) in the same network and domain.
Server B has running IIS-6 with websites(on ports 80, 8080, and others).
Both of them have enabled Firewall.
The problem is that I can't access server B websites by private address in the browser or powershell.
But the website is available from public network
and B responds to ICMP requests from ping

I've added firewall rules(outgoing for A, and incoming for B) but nothing has changed.
I've spent a couple of hours discovering the reasons for this behavior. And I have no idea except, that Citrix(VM's provider) somehow blocks the connection.

**Added:**
Servers have private DNS addresses(assume `servera.local` and `serverb.local`).
When I try to `ping serverb.local` it responds,
and when I try to `curl serverb.local` it doesn't
The same coolstory with the private IP address (10.211...)

At the same time I have serverc.local which (wow) has access to website even without the rule corresponding it its IP address.

Please ask anything, I will add more information if it will help

Comment: You're not using the public DNS record, aren't you? Check out *split-brain DNS*.

Comment: @Zac67, It does not depend on DNS. I've tried to connect by private IP and DNS

Comment: You're not really giving us much detail - or barely any - and public DNS is the most common reason for that problem.

Comment: @Zac67, thanks, I updated the description. Is any other information needed?

Answer (score 1):

If server B is running "websites" (plural), almost certainly they will respond only when they are referenced by name - there has to be a name in the header to tell IIS which web site you're interested in. If you simply talk to an IIS server by IP, generally you'll get a default web site if there is one - there isn't always. So Zac67's suggestion in comments of split-brain DNS is actually appropriate. Or at the very least, edit `\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on server A so there are hosts records that link web address to server B's IP, then try again to connect by name from server A.

Comment: The problem is not the IP and DNS address. I `ping serverb.local` and it answers. And when I try to `curl serverb.local` it doesn't respond anything. I have another server C, which can access website on server B.

Comment: But do you have a web site that is named `serverb.local`? Oh, and the `.local` TLD is special and may not resolve, even locally. I'd create a site `serverb.lan` and try that instead.

Comment: serverb.local resolve without problems. I can ping him, but I can't access port 80

Comment: The question remains: is there a web site on `serverb` named `serverb.local`? In order for IIS to respond to a request for a web site, the `host header` in the request must match the name of a web site that it is hosting, and that means that you have to be making a request by name for a site that has that name.

Comment: Can IIS disable access to website by IP of the client? Because I have `serverc.local` which can access the website

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot help further, but if you will not answer a simple question, there is little point my continuing.

Comment: I have site named ARR with https binding "server.local" on 443 port, and also HTTP binding without hostname on 80 port

Comment: https binding `serverb.local` on 443 port and http binding without hostname on 80 port

Comment: ARR has a lot of https bindings with `serverb.local` hostname on different ports. Other sites have friendly name (no hostname) and one http binding without hostname on different ports.